# cpulimit is not actually limiting CPU usage

Tags: cron, rsync, cpulimit

I'm calling `cpulimit` from `cron`:

`00 16 * * *  /usr/bin/cpulimit --limit 20 /bin/sh /media/storage/sqlbackup/backups.sh`

When the job kicks off, the CPU spikes and alerts as it always has, with no actual identifiable limit having taken place. The job itself iterates over a directory of many subdirectories and performs `rsync`'s each time, which I believe is spawning `rsync` child processes (running top will have a pid available for the called rsync, which after a few minutes will have a different pid for `rsync`).

I'm unsure how to properly utilize `cpulimit` to effectively limit the usage this process consumes.

It might be important to keep in mind this is a VM with 2G RAM and 1vCPU.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `cpulimit` doesn't limit child processes, so the `rsync` is not being limited at all.  If you are running a recent enough version of `cpulimit` you should be able to use the `--include-children` (or `-i`) option.  (See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623698/3281180).)

```
$ cpulimit -h
Usage: cpulimit [OPTIONS...] TARGET
   OPTIONS
      -l, --limit=N          percentage of cpu allowed from 0 to 400 (required)
      -v, --verbose          show control statistics
      -z, --lazy             exit if there is no target process, or if it dies
      -i, --include-children limit also the children processes
      -h, --help             display this help and exit
   TARGET must be exactly one of these:
      -p, --pid=N            pid of the process (implies -z)
      -e, --exe=FILE         name of the executable program file or path name
      COMMAND [ARGS]         run this command and limit it (implies -z)

Report bugs to <marlonx80@hotmail.com>.
```

That would change your cron entry to:

`00 16 * * *  /usr/bin/cpulimit --include-children --limit 20 /bin/sh /media/storage/sqlbackup/backups.sh`

EDIT: As the OP answered (themselves) it would work to `cpulimit` to the `rsync` commands within the script, but that would not ensure that your script is being nice while it is doing other functions.  For example, if the script has to process a massive directory, it could bog down the system and cause a CPU spike and alert.

Comment: I believe that it is `-m, --monitor-forks` instead of `-i` in some versions.